# Making icons selectable in React Native instead of sending them with props

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have svg icons These are `<A/>`, `<B/>`, `<C/>`.

I want to use these icons in `<MyButton>`.

This is how I am using it now.

MyButton.js

```
function MyButton(props) {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity>
      {props.icon}
      <Text>{props.title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

App.js

```
import A from "./A";
import B from "./B";  
import C from "./C";  

function App() {
      return (
        <MyButton icon={<A/>} title={'Example'} />
      );
    }
```

I want the icons to be selectable with string instead of sending them with props. How can I do that?

_App.js

```
function App() {
      return (
        <MyButton icon={"a"} title={'Example'} />
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After so many years working in `react-native`, here is the way I am handeling button icons:

**File structure**

```bash
.
├── App.tsx
├── Button.tsx
├── assets
│   ├── index.ts
│   └── A.tsx
│   └── B.tsx
│   └── C.tsx
```

**assets/A.tsx**: *auto generated by [`SVGR`](https://react-svgr.com/docs/cli/). Can be made manually*

```js
import * as React from "react"
import Svg, { SvgProps, Circle } from "react-native-svg"

const A = (props: SvgProps) => (
  <Svg height={24} width={24} {...props}>
    <Circle cx={50} cy={50} r={40} stroke="black" strokeWidth={3} fill="red" />
  </Svg>
)

export default A
```

**assets/index.ts**: *auto generated by [`SVGR`](https://react-svgr.com/docs/cli/). Can be made manually*

```js
export { default as A } from "./A";
export { default as B } from "./B";
export { default as C } from "./C";
```

**Button.tsx**

```js
// other imports
import * as Icons from "./assets";

interface IIconProps {
  height?: string | number;
  width?: string | number;
  name?: keyof typeof Icons | null; // enable vscode sugestion as well
};

function RenderIcon({ name, ...props }: IIconProps) {
  if (!name) return null;
  const Icon = Icons[name];
  return <Icon {...props} />;
};

interface IButtonProps {
  title?: string;
  icon?: IIconProps;
};

function Button({ icon, title, icon }: IButtonProps) {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity>
      <RenderIcon {...icon} />
      <Text>{title || ""}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

**App.tsx**

```js
function App() {
  return <Button icon={{ name: "A", width: 10, height: 10 }} title="Example" />
}
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: It looks good. So how do you send props to Icon? For example, how can I change the size of the icon?

Answer (score 2):

You can follow this approach. Creating an object of icons, then you can pass icon as string from props to MyButton Component.

```
function MyButton(props) {
  const icons = {
    "a": require("./A"),
    "b": require("./B"),
    "c": require("./C")
  }
  const IconToRender = props.icon ? icons[props.icon] : null;
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity>
      {
        IconToRender ? <IconToRender/> : null
      }
      <Text>{props.title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

Usage

```
 <MyButton icon="a" title="My Title" />
```

Let me know in comments if it helps!

Comment: I think you need create MyIcon component then using it in MyButton

Comment: @Vikas chhabra This is how the packages are used. For example; <Ionicons name="md-checkmark-circle" size={32} color="green" /> Here I am wondering how it works behind the name parameter.

Comment: You can refer to this to explore: https://github.com/expo/vector-icons

Comment: Warning: this approach is recreating the `icons` variable in every component re-render which can lead to performance issues

Answer (score 0):

Your SVG icons are (very probably) React components. I'm afraid there is no (clean/reliable) way to access those components by a string, because they are basically a javascript function (or a "class"), and are not accessible via a string. *(except if already mapped to some object, even if it's the `window` object).*

### string-to-object mapping in javascript

Accessing something "by string" in javascript means finding a string inside a collection, in some way or another, where the "collection" might be an object, an array, or even a string itself.

There is no javascript collection of your components per se, so to be able to select one component "by string", you need to create a collection first, i.e. some list of key-value pairs that associate a string to each component, as other answers already suggested, e.g.

```
const icons = {
    a: A,    // where `A` was imported or required
    b: B,
    ...
}
```

Furthermore, as soon as a React component is "known" to javascript, it takes up memory space.

I.e. as soon as there is a javascript key-to-object mapping, that means that the objects exists from javascripts perspective, so if you have hundreds icons, and a mapping, then you have hundreds of components at once in the memory (while you probably only need a few at a time).

### file system mapping

However, some libraries use specific file names, i.e. they use the file system as a "mapping" (i.e. the key is the file name, the value is the actual file data), and dynamically create an URL, e.g.

file system:

```
/icons/my_smiley-face_icon.svg
/icons/my_home_icon.svg
...
```

code:

```
<MyImage name="smiley-face">

const MyImage = function({ name }){
  return <img src={ '/icons/my_' + name + '_icon.svg' } />
}
```

The URL could be used to `fetch( url )` some image data, or as a source for an `<img>` tag, or incorporated into the DOM in other, possibly weird ways. But they don't use React components here.

### Build time

Other libraries might auto-map icon components to javascript identifiers with some build-time- or pre-build-tools, e.g. some script might read the contents of one specific folder, and even analyzing your code and finding icon names in it, and import only the used components.

Answer (score -1):

**Solution 1**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import A from './A';
import B from './B';
import C from './C';

const MyButton = ({icon, label}) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity>
      {icon == 'a' ? <A /> : icon == 'b' ? <B /> : <C />}
      <Text>{label}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

export default MyButton;



<MyButton icon={"a"} label={"SVG A"} />
<MyButton icon={"b"} label={"SVG B"} />
<MyButton icon={"c"} label={"SVG C"} />
```

**Solution 2**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import A from './A';
import B from './B';
import C from './C';
const ICON_SIZE =20;
const icons_array = {
    "a":<A width={ICON_SIZE} heigth={ICON_SIZE} />,
    "b":<B width={ICON_SIZE} heigth={ICON_SIZE} />,
    "c":<C width={ICON_SIZE} heigth={ICON_SIZE} />
  }
const MyButton = ({icon, label}) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity>
      {icons_array[icon]}
      <Text>{label}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

export default MyButton;


<MyButton icon={"a"} label={"SVG A"} />
<MyButton icon={"b"} label={"SVG B"} />
<MyButton icon={"c"} label={"SVG C"} />
```

Comment: So what do we do when there are hundreds of icons?

Comment: This is a sutible solution for upto five icons. i f u have more icons then u have to create an array of icons and then u can select them.

Comment: How the array should be created and how it should be selected. Can you show me the most performing solution?

Comment: I have updated answer. u can check it now