# How can I make it selectable with string instead of sending props in React or React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

This is how packages are used for React. For example;

`<Ionicons name="md-checkmark-circle" size={32} color="green" />`

Here I am wondering how the name parameter works in the back. Instead of sending the svg icon to the component, I want to make it selectable with a string as in packages like this. How can I do that? I thought it could be done with Array.find() but I wanted to ask to do it in the most correct way. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to send the multiple icon names based on a condition ?

Comment: @Siddharth Mishra No. I want only one icon to be selectable. There may be hundreds of icons, but pick one.

Comment: If you have 100 icons in an array, you can definitely use the find function to get the suitable icon from an array and pass it to the name prop. If you could elaborate the question with some code or screenshots of what exactly you want to achieve, it will be helpful to give you the best possible answer.

Comment: @Siddharth Mishra I have asked in more detail before. You can access it from the link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75538831/making-icons-selectable-in-react-native-instead-of-sending-them-with-props

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making icons selectable in React Native instead of sending them with props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75538831/making-icons-selectable-in-react-native-instead-of-sending-them-with-props)